Is it possible to have multiple wrappers without creating extra classes using fasterxml?
I have to consume xml documents that have multiple nesting levels with each level containing only one single property.
  <xml>
    <level1>
      <level2>
        <level3>
          <actualData>123</actualData>

With @JacksonXmlElementWrapper I can skip creation of one class by defining a wrapper, but as in the xml example, I need extra nesting levels.
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = ["level1", "level2", "level3"]) // localName only accepts one parameter currently
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "actualData")
   private String actualData;

Is there something I can do to have more wrapping levels like the invalid code above avoiding to create more pojo classes for extra nesting levels?

Nested properties of arbitrary depth can be extracted from the topmost parent node by using the at() method and a JsonPointer expression:
public class DataObject {

    private String actualData;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "level1")
    private void unpackActualData(JsonNode level1) {
        actualData = level1.at("/level2/level3/actualData").textValue();
    }

    public String getActualData() {
        return actualData;
    }

    public void setActualData(String actualData) {
        this.actualData = actualData;
    }

}

The textValue() method returns null when no matching node is found. If an empty string is preferable, asText() can be used instead.
